# How to to insert XML values to html with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I need to make put values as shown in html but there is problem with dublicates. when i loop through xml and insert district all districts appear. but i need to remove same districts and leave one.

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
   <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <?php foreach ($list as $record): ?> 
     <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" 
      href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">

    <?php echo $record->district; ?>
                        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </h4>
                </div>
   <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in"role="tabpanel" 
   aria-labelledby="headingOne">
     <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
           <thead>
             <tr>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>work Hours</th>
             </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td> **<address>**  </td>
              <td> **<tel_num>**  </td>
              <td> **<work_range>** </td>
            </tr> 
         </tbody>
       </table>
     </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Store.xml there are many records in this file here is one:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <Regions>
       <m>
        <region>თბილისი</region>
        <district>ვაკე</district>
        <name>ჯიპისი 11(ვაკე)</name>
        <address>თბილისი, ჭავჭავაძის გამზ.  #50</address>
        <coord>41.71,44.7642</coord>
        <tel_num>5 95 22 88 86</tel_num>
        <work_range>24 საათი</work_range>
        <saw>140</saw>
        <dr>2018-02-20T12:36:00+04:00</dr>
        <exp_kl>false</exp_kl>
     </m>
```

Model/Controller

```
public function getStores(){
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('stores.xml');
    $list = $xml->m;
    return $list;
}

public function listAction(){
    $list = $this->model->getStores();
    $vars = [
        'list' => $list,
    ];
    $this->view->render('stores', $vars);
}
```

this is list of stores  is accordion header and when you click one the list of stores appear in this district

the output should look like this:

1. District 1

1) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
2) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
3) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours

2. District 2

1) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
2) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
3) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours

3. District 3

1) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
2) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours
3) 
- Address
- Phone
- Work Hours

Comment: what is your current result?

Comment: <district>, this is not valid HTML, are you using some sort of templating engine? Elaborate better what you are doing

Comment: i inserted **<district>** to show where it should be displayed on website

Comment: this is list of stores **<district>** is accordion header and when you click one the list of stores appear in this district

Comment: You are saying that "all districts appears" in an xml file that shown only 1. Show how you are parsing the xml file and how you are selecting the districts with simplexml

Comment: my current result is: when i use foreach all districts appear, but i need to filter them and leave one district of each

Comment: you do foreach of what exactly? how do you get your $districts exactly?

Comment: are there more <m> nodes in the xml (second snippet of code)? Is that the stores.xml file? write that instead of "XML"

Comment: I don't understand how you can select stuff like $xml->m in your code considering that the most outer node of the xml is Regions.

Comment: does getStores works as expected?

Comment: yes there are many nodes <m>

Comment: yes there is no problem in retrieving data. i have problem in displaying it

Comment: ok let me see if I can help... give me a second

Comment: is the final result you want a list of X panels each one with its header and body where X is the number of items in the store list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you need to find a list of unique districts $list_unique_district as follows:

```
public function getUniqueList() {
  $temp = [];
  foreach ($this->model->getStores() as $record) {
     $temp[] = $record->district;
  }
  return array_unique($temp);
}

public function listAction(){

  $list = $this->model->getStores();
  $unique = $this->model->getUniqueList();

  $vars = [
    'list_unique_district' => $unique,
    'list' => $list,
  ];
  $this->view->render('stores', $vars);
}
```

After that loop all districts and where you print the table rows go through every element in the original list of "m" and check if its district is equal the currently processed one.

```
<?php foreach ($list_unique_district as $current_district): ?> 

  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
            <?php echo $current_district; ?>
          </a>  
        </h4>

    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Address</th>
              <th>Phone</th>
              <th>work Hours</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($list as $record): ?> 
              <?php if ($list->district == $current_district ?> 

                <tr>
                  <td> <?php $record->address; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php $record->tel_num; ?> </td>
                  <td> <?php $record->work_range; ?> </td>
                </tr> 

              <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: i tried to do like this but in this case if i have similar districts both appear like: if several <m> have for example <district>test</district> all of them will appear in list but i need to leave only one

Comment: Oh so you are saying that you need to group together all the m with the same district?

Comment: is this what you want?

Comment: If the answer is correct I would gently ask you to mark it as correct otherwise let me know what's wrong with it

Comment: honestly i don't know how to help you more than what I did.